# Drupal 8.0 to 8.1.8 upgradation is not working

Tags: 8, upgrading

When i tried to update drupal to latest version (**8.1.8**) am getting  the following error
 [image]

But in the **`status report`** page it shows as upgraded to **8.1.8**

[image]

[image]

Any idea how to resolve this ??

Comment: It says the errors have been logged, do you see any errors in your log? What if you update to 8.1.0 first, do you get the same errors?

Comment: Didnt tried 8.1.0 . In the error log the same error as **undefined offset in DbUpdateController**

Answer (score 0):

The message is a notice not a error so updating of core just went on. So you core is now on the latest version.

You should however solve the error.